# What is the maximum possible degrees of a vertex of an MST

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

What is the number that a minimum spanning tree can have a vertex with degree at most? Is there any rule? Is it related to the number of vertex or edge? Or not?

Comment: A minimum spanning tree could be a star, and so have a vertex of degree $n-1$, where $n$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: Ok, then at most n-1

Comment: @LSG Yes but that applies to any vertex of any $n$-vertex graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the graph is already a tree. Then the minimum spanning tree is the graph itself. In particular, if we take a star on $n$ vertices, we obtain a minimum spanning tree having a vertex of degree $n-1$. This is optimal, since in a graph containing $n$ vertices, all degrees are at most $n-1$.